# change telerik upload browse button style

Tags: asp.net, upload, telerik, styles

I'm using Telerik Upload Control in my ASP.NET web app, I'm going to change style of its browse button. I've tested several things with no success. How can change width, height, and background image of this button? can you tell me correct css for this button?

Comment: Can you post the HTML that the Telerik Upload control renders? That way people not familar with Telerik, but who know CSS, can help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Telerik upload control. What HTML does it render?

My guess is it's just a wrapper around the `<input type="file" />` element. In which case I'm afraid you're a bit short of luck: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

Most workarounds involve using Flash (Flickr does this) or scripting (imgur.com does this), but neither approaches are perfect.

Comment: Telerik supports styling but I don't know exactly how to set styles